# Does libgit2 support a ssh config host alias?

Tags: ssh, libgit2

I am using a ssh host alias, as in:

.ssh/config

```
Host my-git-host
    HostName github.com
```

And the command-line git works for push/pull/clone using my-git-host as a remote etc.
But would this also work through libgit2 as is ?
I am using an application that uses libgit2 and it fails to push/pull with an error - as though it were trying to dns resolve my-git-host.

### thx,

Comment: This shouldn't be a libgit2 issue -- assuming that libgit2 just calls `ssh`, it is entirely up to `ssh` to parse the configuration file. The thing calling `ssh` doesn't know anything about it. If you can update your question to show an example of failing code, a specific error message, etc, we would be better able to help  you.

Comment: The error I see is:
git error:failed to resolve address for my-git-host: Name or service not known; class=Net (12)
I thought this was coming from socket.c:
 if ((ret = p_getaddrinfo(st->host, st->port, &hints, &info)) != 0) {
  git_error_set(GIT_ERROR_NET,
      "failed to resolve address for %s: %s", st->host, p_gai_strerror(ret));
  return -1;
 }

Comment: I suppose there is a way for libgit2 to use ssh/libssh and not try to connect directly ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I discovered the application I'm using uses git2-rs which uses libgit2 but perhaps not with ssh support.
thx